# Encoding of key codes (virtual?) send to virtualbox-guest-system

Tags: java, keycode

How to send a string to a virtualbox-guest-machine?

This is my code:

```
public void testKeyboard() throws Exception {
    IVirtualBox b = connect();
    List<IMachine> machines = b.getMachines();
    for (IMachine m : machines) {
        MachineState d = b.getMachineStates(Arrays.asList(m)).iterator().next();
        if (d == MachineState.Running) {
            ISession s = manager.getSessionObject();
            m.lockMachine(s, LockType.Shared);
            IConsole console = s.getConsole();
            IKeyboard k = console.getKeyboard();
            k.putScancodes(Arrays.asList(25, 25 | 0x80)); // <- sends the character P
            s.unlockMachine();
        }
    }
}
```

[Microsoft say its 0x50](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

java.awt.event.KeyEvent also say its 0x50:

```
/** Constant for the "P" key. */
 public static final int VK_P = 0x50;
```

In virtualbox its different.
P=25
2=0x50
b=0x30

Why in the world is the code of P = 25 in virtualbox?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you talking about the letter D or the letter P? If it's P, then where do you get this "25" from? It's 0x50, both in Java and Microsoft.

Comment: @k314159 25 was a wild guess. I was supprised that 25 gives the charater P. I talk about P. I had a typo in the question, I hope the confusion is gone.

Comment: Keyboard scan codes are not ascii - they are dependent on keyboard layouts.  Is the fundamental question - "how do I know the scan codes for characters on my keyboard?" or something similar?  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode.  Note - it gets a bit complex, you have to send one for key down, one for key up etc.  What are you trying to send longer term?

Comment: Look at Appendix C in this doc for the mappings for USB keyboards: https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc  .  You can see that key P is in position 26, if the scan codes are 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed like the table, then P would be 25.  If this is what you're after, I can write it up into a proper answer.

Comment: I thought about scancodes too, but since P is 25, not 26 I neglect this idea. Are you guys sure there is not a different approach? I can not imagine that oracle mixed up 0-indexed and 1-indexed.

Comment: Yeah it is scancodes, I built the same thing to control VirtualBox VM a few years ago in Rust, see my scancode table at the time: https://github.com/laech/arch-zfs-iso/blob/fa1ca01a3c5be532d386ac5dcba9dcbf5088b68f/test/src/scancode.rs#L55-L103 and how I was translating strings to scancodes: https://github.com/laech/arch-zfs-iso/blob/fa1ca01a3c5be532d386ac5dcba9dcbf5088b68f/test/src/vm.rs#L118-L129

Answer (score 2):

Virtual key codes and keyboard scan codes are two different things.

Keyboards (still) talk to PCs using a really dusty old protocol. Many years ago I implemented a toy version of the protocol in an OS driver and it was quite annoying. Making it worse, keyboards can use 3 different sets of keyboard scancodes which originated with different flavors of old PCs.

Here is a reference for the 3 sets: https://www.vetra.com/scancodes.html

The constants you discovered line up with Set 1. Note that Set 1 has different codes used to press the key and release the key!

The virtual key constants used by the Java KeyEvent class and by that Windows list both seem to be based closely on ASCII characters, since 'P' = 0x50 in ASCII. But it's the job of the operating system keyboard driver to translate from keyboard scancodes to more logical sets of constants. There is no universal constant for a key.

Since VirtualBox is emulating the physical keyboard interface to the guest OS, its `IKeyboard` API takes raw scancodes.

For the VirtualBox GUI, it must have a function which translates from host OS key constants back to scancodes for the guest OS, which might be easier if you can use that, but `IKeyboard` appears to be a very low-level interface which bypasses that.

Depending on your use case, perhaps there is a different API you can also use here; or perhaps you can control your VM with guest software like SSH or VNC.

Comment: I gave Snape the bounty. Althou you had the same answer. I upvoted yours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Scan codes are keyboard layout dependent mappings to key layouts.  You can send codes based on the scan codes for a USB keyboard, which all modern systems are likely to understand.  The codes are documented in Appendix C of the Microsoft document "Keyboard Scan Code Specification".  You will see there that character `P` is in position 26 in the 1-indexed table of key location.  This would explain a 0-indexed code of 25 producing the character `P`.

You will see that "key down" needs you to send 25 as the scan code (0x19) and then 0x99 for key up.  This is what your (25 | 0x80) is doing.  So your code at the moment sends a message meaning "Key P has been pressed (make in the table)" followed by "Key P has been released (break in the table)"

The direct link to the doc I'm referencing here is: https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc

**N.B.** These codes are quite different to ASCII codes, which are where you are getting the 0x50 from.

#### Sending strings via the keyboard

If you want to send a whole string via the keyboard this way, what you will need is a mapping table from ASCII codes for each character to key make and key break codes.  You can then take the string character by character and work out which scan code pairs to send for each character. Note - you'll need to deal with case by adding a "Shift down" before the pair and "Shift up" afterwards.  This is do-able with a fairly long mapping table, I'd use a `WeakHashMap`